# Live Search return several columns from MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have been able to implement Live Search to my XHTML page. But I have 2 issues:

1. I want it to return more than one item, which I have not been able to do and is very important.
2. I want to capitalize the first letter from each word, since if I search with a uppercase letter, that letter in every word turns uppercase. I tried with CSS capitalize but that gives no results in the input box.

This is my code:

```
$(function(){
$(".search").keyup(function() 
{ 
var searchid = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'search='+ searchid;
if(searchid!='')
{
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
    $("#result").html(html).show();
    }
    });
}return false;    
});

jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.name').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid').val(decoded);


});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
```

This is what I tried but is not working in addition to the code above:

```
jQuery("#result").live("click",function(e){ 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    var $name = $clicked.find('.telefone').html();
    var decoded = $("<div/>").html($name).text();
    $('#searchid1').val(decoded);
});
jQuery(document).live("click", function(e) { 
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.hasClass("search1")){
    jQuery("#result").fadeOut(); 
    }
});
$('#searchid1').click(function(){
    jQuery("#result").fadeIn();
});
```

And this is the PHP:

```
$strSQL_Result = mysqli_query($connection,"select Nome,Email,Telefone from Contactos where Nome like '%$q%' order by Nome LIMIT 15");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($strSQL_Result))
{
    $username   = $row['Nome'];
    $b_username = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
    $final_username = str_ireplace($q, $b_username, $username);
    $telefone   = $row['Telefone'];
    $b_telefone = '<strong>'.$q.'</strong>';
    $final_telefone = str_ireplace($q, $b_telefone, $telefone);
    ?>
        <div class="show" align="left">
            <span class="name"><?php echo $final_username; ?></span>&nbsp;<br/>
            <span class="telefone"><?php echo $final_telefone; ?></span>&nbsp;<br/>
        </div>
```